# Restrict access to data in OData $expand operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have two entities from my database exposed in an ASP.NET WebApi 2 OData: service `Employee` and `Activity`. For simplicity, let's assume they look like this:

```
public class Employee {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Activity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee OpenedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that the `OpenedBy` property corresponds to a navigation property, e.g. I can run the following OData query:

```
GET http://localhost/odata/Activities?$expand=OpenedBy
```

I would like to block certain Employee types from being shown in OData. Let's assume I can't do this on the data source, so I have to do it in code.

What I've done so far is to block these types in the EmployeesController (inherits from EntitySetController):

```
[Queryable]
public override IQueryable<Employee> Get() {
    return dbContext.Employees.Where(e => e.Type != "Restricted").AsQueryable();
}

[Queryable]
protected override Employee GetEntityByKey([FromODataUri] int key) {
    var employee = dbContext.Employees.Find(key);
    if (employee == null || employee.Type == "Restricted") {
        throw new ODataException("Forbidden");
    }

    return employee;
}
```

This works fine. However, I noticed that if I run the query:

```
GET http://localhost/odata/Activities?$expand=OpenedBy
```

I do not hit the code in the Employees controller and consequently the restricted employee records are visible. What is a good way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

In this case: http://localhost/odata/Activities?$expand=OpenedBy

I think you should change the code in ActivitiesController, **$expand** will hit **Get Activity method** there.

If you do not want to expand the OpenedBy all the time, you can add an attribute: 
        **[NotExpandable]**

Hope this can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "I noticed that if I run the query" I get the impression that this is a side-effect that you are happy to restrict in all circumstances.  If this is the case [this article by Mike Wasson](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-security-guidance) could be of use to you.

In that article he suggests two methods to restrict odata access to a property:

1. An attribute on your model
2. Programmatically removing it from your EDM

I didn't try the first and I'm not sure which namespace or libraries you would need to do it but, in the case of the question it would look like this:

```
public class Activity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Employee OpenedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I have used the second method and this would look something like this for the example given in the question:

```
var activities = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Activity>("Activities");
activities.EntityType.Ignore(a => a.OpenedBy);
```

I have restricted some navigational Collections this way and it works very well.